# In parent swiftui view how could I know when a state changes in an inner views viewmodel void method?

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui, combine

Given an AuthenticationView swiftui struct contains a UserLoginView. The UserLoginView has a UserLoginViewModel class for handle the login button actions.

In the AuthenticationView I would like to know when the value of the variable changes in the inner UserLoginView (if the tutorialScreenIsShowable is true in AuthenticationView, the NavigationLink navigate to next slide).

```
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    @State private var tutorialScreenIsShowable = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: TutorialView(), isActive: $tutorialScreenIsShowable) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                UserLoginView(tutorialScreenIsShowable: self.$tutorialScreenIsShowable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

,

```
struct UserLoginView: View {
    @Binding var tutorialScreenIsShowable: Bool
    @ObservedObject var userLoginViewModel = UserLoginViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.userLoginViewModel.loginButtonAction() // it not works but I need this way
//            self.tutorialScreenIsShowable = self.userLoginViewModel.loginButtonActionWithReturn() // it works, but its not good in this case
        }) {
            Text("Log in")
        }
    }
}
```

,

```
class UserLoginViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var tutorialScreenIsShowable = false
    
    func loginButtonAction() {
        self.tutorialScreenIsShowable = true
    }
    
    func loginButtonActionWithReturn() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

As I know if the function would have a return value that could be work, but in this case there is a delegate method running where I can handle the variable.

I'd like to avoid @EnvironmentObject as it possible, I hope there is another solution.

Could you help me with this?

Edit: I simplified the example. And uploaded a example project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/paosp6iom9oks9p/InnerViewPropBind.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of this behaviour is in `NavigationView` with recreates own content many times during update.

Here is a possible solution - some redesign and ownership changes.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

```
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    // keep model here to avoid recreation inside navigation view
    @ObservedObject var userLoginViewModel = UserLoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                // use binding directly in view model
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("TutorialView"), isActive: $userLoginViewModel.tutorialScreenIsShowable) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

                UserLoginView(userLoginViewModel: userLoginViewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserLoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userLoginViewModel: UserLoginViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.userLoginViewModel.loginButtonAction()
        }) {
            Text("Log in")
        }
    }
}

class UserLoginViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var tutorialScreenIsShowable = false

    func loginButtonAction() {
        self.tutorialScreenIsShowable = true
    }

    func loginButtonActionWithReturn() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, but unfortunately its not work. ): The NavigationLink not navigate to the next slide.

Comment: Well, navigation is different issue. You cannot navigate being in modal view, at first you have to close modal one.

Comment: The navigation works if the loginWithGoogleButtonAction would have a return value (self.tutorialScreenIsShowable = self.userLoginViewModel.loginWithGoogleButtonAction()
). So that could be not problem. Otherwise, I also tried controlled by the property the visibility of a view, but it didn't change either.

Comment: Does `didSignInFor` callback received? On main queue? If yes for first, but no for second it should be added redirection to main dispatch queue. I cannot test your API dependent part.

Comment: Please check again the example, I cleared the code, there is no api now. And I linked my sample project. I hope it could be cleaner. Thanks!!

Comment: I like this! That's pretty! Thank you very much!